С ним или С ними?
Как правильно в данном случае, с ним или с ними? Без разборок с охраной до Василия не добраться.

У меня есть приятель, который задолжал мне денег. Зовут его Василий. Проживает здесь недалеко, возле парка. Охрана у него что надо, так что он там как за каменной стеной. Поэтому нужен человек, такой как ты, чтобы разобраться с ним.

или

У меня есть приятель, который задолжал мне денег. Зовут его Василий. Проживает здесь недалеко, возле парка. Охрана у него что надо, так что он там как за каменной стеной. Поэтому нужен человек, такой как ты, чтобы разобраться с ними.


Если речь идёт и об охране, и о Василии,то: с ними. Если речь идёт только о Василии, тогда: с ним. Если только об охране —  с ней.
